# pptx4j duplicate data when drawing graphs

Tags: java, powerpoint, openxml, docx4j

I must have a bad understanding of OpenXML, but I do not understand why when drawing a graph in a power point presentation using [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j), one must :

- create an embedded excel file (`data.xlsx`) with data series
- create an xml file (`chart_data.xml`) with link to data series

AND

- populate `chart_data.xml` with `strCache` elements containing data from `data.xlsx`. We are duplicating the data series.

It seems like power point only uses elements from `strCache` to populate its graph. If they are missing, the graph is not displayed.

Why do we need to create both an excel worksheet and an xml file with the same data in it ?

Are the link we declare between the graph object and the embedded excel sheet used for something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PowerPoint to create a pptx and insert a chart, it adds the XLSX as well.

In the chart part's xml, the c:externalData element points to the XLSX.

If you don't have the c:externalData element, you don't need to create the Excel worksheet.  But leaving it out affects user's ability to edit the chart in Powerpoint.

Curiously, c:externalData has child c:autoUpdate but it doesn't work as described at http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/DrawingML/autoUpdate.html

Above is based on testing in Powerpoint 2010 only; things may be different in 2013 or 2016.

Comment: indeed, I tested the c:autoUpdate : it has stricly no effect, the behavioour of power pointdoes not change with this flag

Comment: Hi Jason, I tested it with power point also, it seems like this cache data is *mandatory* to get something drawnd when opening the power point file. If this cache data is not present, one must open the graph in power point and access the embedded ws to get the graph drawn...     So it leaves us with 2 possibilities : `1 - Draw a graph only by populating the graph_data.xml with cache data : graph is not editable`. `2 - populate graph_data.xml AND an embedded xlsx document, adding the c:externalData element : graph is editable`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Another option which might be of interest is to generate your graph using a third party library, such as R, JFreeChart or XChart, then just insert a PNG.  But its not editable from within Office.

Comment: If only we could ! This is the easy solution, but our client wants this power point graphs feeling... using the library for a few weeks now it feels like it is designed for working with templates and not creating files from scratch really, right ?